# weird marks at the end of line in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

I am using vscode, and recently in the editor it has started showing a color mark at the end of line (see attached screenshot for reference). I am not sure what I pressed, which enabled this behaviour. Does anyone know how to disable this?
[image]

(I am vim for vscode extension, don't know if that has anything to do with this, may be pressed some vim keystrokes unkowingly which enabled this.)

Comment: That really just looks like some sort of trailing whitespace highlighter.  Did you install any kind of extension that highlights trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last search in vim was for end-of-line `/$` and stayed highlighted.

Use `:noh` to clear highlights.